# Select Dates for Weekends Only

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to query my mongoDB collection to return documents that include the field `selectedDate` and check if the date string falls on a weekend (saturday[6] or sunday[0]).

How do I pass the field's value to the function to check it? `data` returns undefined but I am unsure how to store it in a var properly.

Query

```
Entry.
  find({}).
  where('selectedDate').equals(thisWeekend(data)).
  exec(function(err, entries) {
    console.log('Events on a weeked' + ' ' + entries);
  });
```

Function

```
function thisWeekend(data) {
  var today = data.getDay();
  if (today == 6 || today == 0) {
    console.log('WEEKEND BITCHES');
  } else {
    console.log('Not the weekend');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't do it like that, you do it like this:

```
Entry.aggregate(
    [
        { "$redact": {
            "$cond": {
                "if": {
                    "$or": [
                        { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfWeek": "$selectedDate" }, 1 ] },
                        { "$eq": [ { "$dayOfWeek": "$selectedDate" }, 7 ] }
                    ]
                },
                "then": "$$KEEP",
                "else": "$$PRUNE"
            }
        }}
    ],
    function(err,results) {
       if (err) throw err;
       // results is weekend days only
    }
)
```

The [`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) pipeline operator does filtering of documents by a logical expression, here using [`$dayOfWeek`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dayOfWeek) to find the weekday value.

The alternate case is a [`$where`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/where/) expression, but since this does require JavaScript evaluation, it actually runs much slower than the aggregation operation. You really should only use this with MongoDB 2.4 or earlier releases that do not have `$redact`:

```
Entry.find(
    {
        "$where": function() {
            var day = this.selectedDate.getUTCDay();
            return ( day == 6 || day == 0 );
         }
    },
    function(err,results) {
        if (err) throw err;
        // Just weekends
    }
)
```

Where you really should be calling `.getUTCDay()` here against a date that is in UTC.

Comment: Thanks for this, it seems like a step in the right direction, however `results` returns as `undefined`. Is there another piece I am missing?

Comment: @RhysEdwards It's likely your "dates" are not actually `Date` objects but "strings". But there really should be an error if they where, Check the `err` response to be sure.

Comment: @RhysEdwards My bad! Honestly 3 out of 4 times I type a `$redact` expression in an answer here I aways forget to include the `$cond`. Corrected.

Comment: Ah okay great! Yep the dates are currently stored as strings but that's an easy fix. Thanks!

Comment: @RhysEdwards  What does the very last line of the answer here say? MongoDB Dates are "UTC" . So the date returned in **not** a Monday, but when it is being "stringified" JavaScript uses the "local time string" to display the result.Your local offset is different from UTC by 1 hour. So work it out. Still does not change that the underlying date is of course still UTC.